# How to speed up bulk update in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Got a script that was running very fast (about 20 seconds to process 30,000 records) when I am processing 100,000 records or thereabouts. The scripts grabs records from a postgresql database, processes them and then marks in the database that those records have been processed.

Problem is I've now pointed the scripts to a database with 50 million records and now  10,000 records are taking about 160 seconds! That is extremely slow.

Is there something I can do to speed up my updates?

my python and SQLAlchemy Core code are:

```
def process_records(no_of_records, data)
    for x in range(no_of_records):
        my_data = data[x]
            '''process the data, when done, mark as is_processed'''
        dict = {}
        dict['b_id'] = pid
        dict['is_processed'] = is_processed
        is_processed_list.append(dict)

    CONN = Engine.connect()
    trans = CONN.begin()
    stmt = mytable.update().where(mytable.c.id == bindparam('b_id')).\
    values(is_processed=bindparam('is_processed'))
    CONN.execute(stmt, is_processed_list)
    trans.commit()
```

**EDIT**

I profiled my code and I realized that the problem was not with this python loop or even with the bulk insert. The problem `where I was loosing 80+ seconds` was in selecting the data to process in the first place. Once I figured that out then @Martin's suggestion I included an index and its back to rocket speeds!

Comment: (In clippy voice): It appears you're processing each row in its own transaction. Have you considered processing many rows in one transaction at a time?

Comment: @ScottMarlowe am actually doing a bulk update. If you check the syntax carefully, the update statement comes after the for loop i.e. the update statement runs the `is_processed_list` which has about 10,000 records for each update. The for loop is very fast. Runs in microseconds. only the bulk update is taking God knows forever.

Comment: Ahh ok. Yeah it wasn't that obvious to me from your code. Well glad you found your real issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check what the query planner tells you. Prefix your SQL query with "EXPLAIN" to get details about what Postgresql is trying to do. First, just try to SELECT rows that should be updated to see what happens.

If it's the selection part that is slow (reading), it might be fastened by using an index on this condition (mytable.c.id == b_id). Note that in Postgresql, a FOREIGN KEY will not index your table.

See here for details about EXPLAIN: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

If it's the writing part that is slow, you may need to tune the configuration of Postgresql.

Comment: You got it spot on. I assumed that a foreign key is indexed by default. So I've created an index on that column and the select statement is now Micro Seconds. Doesn't even feel like its 50Million records! For tuning though, I have a 16GB machine running ubuntu server with 8 cores. I've edited the config to include kernel.shmmax = 4294967296, kernel.shmall = 1073741824 and set shared_buffers = 3500MB. More suggestions welcome